# How do I fix these black seams on my object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, subdivision-surface

Okay so this question sounds pretty weird but hear me out.

My problem is this:[image]

Do you see the black seams running between parts of the texture? (It looks way worse when the camera is pointing from the bottom). This problem became a problem because I used the "Subdivide Smooth" tool on just the upper parts of the snow that didn't touch the stone. Above the seam is where I used subdivide smooth, and below the seam is where I didn't. Clearly the cause of this is that I used subdivide smooth on part of the mesh but not all of it, and the non-smooth and smooth parts of the mesh are interacting all weird.
Here is what the seam looks like in edit mode (A top down view), [image]
Okay so the problem is pretty obvious here. Do you see the part of the mesh that juts out, yet isn't an edge? That's my "Seam" that is being incredibly annoying, I think the reason you get those black lines is because it's jutting out and casting a shadow onto the mesh below it.

Now I've found a "solution" to this problem. The solution is that I delete the face that has the seam, and then I make two smaller faces (this isn't a subdivision by the way, so I can't just automate this process). Here is an example of this:[image]
Now I know what you're thinking. "Congrats you answered your own question, thanks for wasting my time." But the reality is that this problem is prevalent across the entire object and I'd have to do this process like, a thousand times, in order to fix the whole entire object. I'm just wondering if there might be a way to solve this problem in one go, rather than having to do each face individually.

I get this was long so thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you have holes that make those black lines, fill them by selecting everything in editmode, pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> and typing "Fill Holes" and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Next if you had no holes or if you successfully filled them press <kbd>Space</kbd> again and type "Degenerate Dissolve" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Try to increase the Merge Distance in the Toolshelf if it does not work immediately.